# Что такое import sys и sys.exit?

Tags: python, импорт, sys

Друг помог с исправлением кода, но так и не понял что это за функции. 
Что такое `import sys` и `sys.exit`?

```
import sys
print("Привет! Это программа создана для перевода из десятичной сисетмы в любые другие системы счисления")
print("")
while True:    

    a = int(input("Введите число которое хотите конвертировать: "))

    n = int(input("Введите систему в которую хотите перевести число: "))

    s = ""

    while a > 0:

            s = str(a % n) + s 

            a //= n
    print(s)
    cnt = int(input(('Введите 1, что бы продолжить или 0 для завершения работы: ')))
    if cnt == 0:
          break
sys.exit()
```

Comment: У вас и так программа в конце закончится, вам это не нужно. Вот если бы посередине программы нужно было выйти. Это выход из программы на питоне такой хитрый.

Comment: я просто не могу понять что такое sys exit, не понимаю что написано в интернете

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Библиотека - sys предназначена для операций над системой и порядком исполнения программы. Строка sys.exit предназначена для выхода из приложения и завершения его работы, то-есть не придётся в ручную закрывать приложение через кнопки сверху, за это вас сделает код. Это очень нужно для всяких игр в полноэкранном режиме.

Библиотека sys так же предоставляет возможность задавать параметры программы во время запуска её через командную строку.

Пример -
Программа по выводу чисел -

Ввод:cmd.exe - python main.py
Вывод: Введите число!(вы ввели число 5)
Вывод: Вы ввели число 5!

Программа по выводу чисел, пример 2 -

Ввод: cmd.exe - python main.py 6
Вывод: Вы ввели число 6!

Это очень примерно и допущено много условностей, но я думаю вы поняли.

Помните! Программирование это легко, это лишь набор инструкций. Как план военного наступления, тоже набор инструкций. Тоже слова переведённые в инструкции которые должны быть понимаемы как для составителя инструкций(программиста) как и для исполнителя(компилятора). Удачи с изучением! Надеюсь из вас получится отличный специалист!